# How to create users in Ms Sql server 7 only allowed to connect in the local network

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if it's possible to create a user (or modify an existing one) in Ms Sql server that can only connect to the DDBB using an internal IP and not an external IP. Something similar to Mysql, that allows you to specify the host. Sorry if it is a very easy question but I am not expert at all in SQL server!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to clarify what you mean by "an internal IP".

If you mean, on the MS SQL box itself, this is trivial by only binding to localhost (127.0.0.1).

If you mean, from a list of allowed remote IPs - employ a firewall.

What on earth has possessed you to EVER open up MS SQL to an externally-reachable port.
It is the number one cause of hacked databases.

Comment: I mean an IP inside the LAN, for example 192.168.2.X. We were using a VPN connection to access those databases but the router stopped working and in the meantime we need to open the external connections

Comment: +1 for do not externally expose FW!

Answer (score 0):

I would do that via Windows firewall.  It should have a default rule for SQL Server (assuming you didn't turn the FW off.  You can limit it to IP ranges, etc.

Thanks,
Eric